# Not sure how to pass parameters from class to constructor in main()

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor, fstream

My assignment is to read from a gradbook text file and average every students' program, midterm and final scores, as well as the student ID and the first and last name. So far, code is able to compile and calculates the scores appropriately, but it won't read the studentID and first and last name.

I'm pretty sure the reason why is that the currentStudent variable in main() doesn't have any parameters and makes the constructor use default values. But I'm not sure how to give currentStudent values from class Student while in main(). My best idea for a solution is to move everything from ReadData into main(), but from the description of ReadData from my assignment, I think I have everything I need in there:

"A method called ReadData(istream&) which reads the Student's data. It reads the ID number (integer), first and last names (strings) in that order, the 10 program scores (all integers) and the midterm and exam scores (also integers). It returns true if all data was read successfully, otherwise false"

I'm sorry for the long-winded description, I'm just seeing if I can effectively explain my situation. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

I've only included the class definition, constructor, ReadData, and main below because everything else is just equations and get/sets that I'm pretty sure all work, and I'm trying to lessen what you lovely people would have to read through. If anyone would like to see the full code, I'll post the rest.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
private:
    int studentID;
    string firstName,
    lastName;
    int score[ 10 ];
    int midterm, final;
public:
    Student ( int, string, string );
    bool ReadData ( istream& );
    //fstream WriteData ( ostream& ); // I need to clear up with professor first
    void setStudentID ( int );
    void setFirstName ( string );
    void setLastName ( string );
    void setMidterm ( int );
    void setFinal (int );
    const int getStudentID ( );
    const string getFirstName ( );
    const string getLastName ( );
    const int getMidterm ( );
    const int getFinal ( );
    void setProgramScore ( int, int[ ] );
    int getProgramScore ( int );
    const double ProgramAvg( );
    const double CourseAvg( );
    ~Student( );
};

Student::Student ( int id = 0, string f = "", string l = "" )
{
    setStudentID ( id );
    setFirstName ( f );
    setLastName ( l );
};

bool Student::ReadData( istream &readStudent ) 
{
    int id;
    string first, last;
    int x[ 10 ], mid, fin;

    readStudent >> id >> first >> last;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++ )
    {
        readStudent >> x [ i ];
        setProgramScore( i, x );
    }
    readStudent >> mid >> fin;

    Student studentInfo ( id, first, last );
    setMidterm( mid );
    setFinal( fin );

    if ( readStudent.good( ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
```

// getters, setters and calculations in between

```
int main( )
{
    ifstream readStudent;
    int lineCount = 0;
    double totalProgramAvg = 0
        , totalFinalAvg = 0
        , totalCourseAvg = 0;

    Student currentStudent; 
    readStudent.open ( "gradebook.txt" );
    if ( readStudent.is_open ( ) )
    {

        while ( currentStudent.ReadData ( readStudent ) == true )
        {
            totalProgramAvg += currentStudent.ProgramAvg();
            totalFinalAvg += currentStudent.getFinal();
            totalCourseAvg += currentStudent.CourseAvg();
            cout << currentStudent.getStudentID() << " "
                << currentStudent.getFirstName() << " "
                << currentStudent.getLastName() << " ";
            for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
                cout << currentStudent.getProgramScore( j ) << " ";
            cout << currentStudent.getMidterm() << " "
                << currentStudent.getFinal() << endl;
            cout <<  totalProgramAvg << " " << totalCourseAvg << endl;
            lineCount++;
        };
    readStudent.close( );

        cout << lineCount << endl << totalProgramAvg / lineCount << "\n" <<     totalFinalAvg / lineCount << "\n" << totalCourseAvg / lineCount;

    system ("pause");
    };
};
```

Comment: This code reads the first and last names correctly for me. I strongly suggest that you [minimize this code](http://sscce.org); you may well find the bug along the way, and if you don't it leaves us much less work to do. Also, when you are developing a new function, do so **in isolation,** don't try to get it working in tandem with a lot of other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool Student::ReadData( istream &readStudent ) 
{
    int id;
    string first, last;
    int x[ 10 ], mid, fin;

    readStudent >> id >> first >> last;

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++ )
    {
        readStudent >> x [ i ];
        setProgramScore( i, x );
    }
    readStudent >> mid >> fin;

    Student studentInfo ( id, first, last );
    setMidterm( mid );
    setFinal( fin );

    if ( readStudent.good( ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}; //what?
```

I haven't checked the rest of your code, but this is certainly erroneous.

You shouldn't be declaring a new item `Student studentInfo(  id, first, last);`   You're creating a new item that just dies when the function returns.  Instead, you should use id,first,last to modify a current object member  you're in, `this`.  You have declared items for this in your class header but then declare local scope variables, use them, create a new student with it, and then all are destroyed when the function returns and they go out of scope.  Simply delete/add things where I mark appropriate from the function to get

```
bool Student::ReadData( istream &readStudent ) 
{
    int x[ 10 ], mid, fin; //if it ain't broke, don't fix it

    readStudent >> studentID >> firstName >> lastName;  //use your class members that you want to hold that data.  

    for ( int i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++ )
    {
        readStudent >> x [ i ];
        setProgramScore( i, x );
    }
    readStudent >> mid >> fin;


    setMidterm( mid );
    setFinal( fin );

    if ( readStudent.good( ) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

You can directly access class members in the class function `Student::ReadData( istream &readStudent)` and you should just do it for all of them but you said the score system was working so I left that alone.

Finally, `;` goes after `}` if it's like a `struct`, or a `class`, or a bunch of `stuff` I don't know, but not a function definition.

Okay, I see another bug /flaw in your project flow:

`while ( currentStudent.ReadData ( readStudent ) == true ) { /*stuff*/ }` is not going to work right.   Your ReadData function is going to read in all the data for your current student, but the while loop is also going to try to do that.  I can't fathom the result but it will be ugly no doubt.  Your better to use it like this:

```
if(!(currentStudent.ReadData( readStudent)) {
     //Ooops, I failed, what do I do?
}
```